# Angular 4: CORS Issue on Post using ionic 3 angular 4

Tags: angular, laravel-5, ionic3

I really appreciate the guidance I'm getting from the community. Hence, i would like to ask a question please do note that I have exhausted all my resources and Google to figure out a solution for the issue:

Front-End: Using ionic3 angular 4

Back-End: Using Laravel 5.4

What we have tried so far:

Front End:

- Installed cordova whitelist plugin
- Added Proxy Url in config.xml

Back End:

- Added whitelisting and header for Laravel

The Issue:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>
> http://52.76.26.109/beacon/public/api/phonebook/create. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Any valuable input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Additional: I forgot to mention that GET requests via http works while the POST doesn't.

Comment: did you try with jsonp ? as its a crossorigin request.

Comment: Hi @ASLAMTP is this something to try on the Front End or Back? if so can you provide a sample implementation thanks

Comment: May be your porxy were not added correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS & Laravel CORS, POST stops after preflights OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213329/angularjs-laravel-cors-post-stops-after-preflights-options)

Comment: Its better to handle these sort of request from server side. As its going to be a security concern. Dont make a cross domain request from client side

Comment: try to remove .htaccess file from your laravel application if cors doesnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be getting this error only from the browser. Cordova plugins are disabled when using your browser and hence the whitelist plugin will be disabled when testing on your browser. When you take a build and install it on your mobile it will start working. If you would like to test the API from your browser. You should install a [CORS plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) and enable it. Then, your http requests will go through. You need not use JSONP requests.. You can just use your normal http requests

Comment: Thanks! will try this suggestion and give you an update. Yes I am developing the app from my laptop so in a developer standpoint its much easier to check for bugs on the machine rather than redeploying it every time on the device

Comment: @AlfredM. If you found the answer helpful, please mark it as correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is caused by CORS.

the simple solution is to adds CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers support in your Laravel project.

I suggest you use this package:[laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

If you already add a header for you laravel project.Then you should double check those headers and make sure headers are added.

If you added correctly, the response header should have an item 
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

Comment: Thanks! will try this one and update you with the results